# Why checkout_onepage_controller_success_action is dispatched after the layout is loaded?

Tags: event-observer, onepage-checkout

Is there any reason `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event is dispatched after the layout is loaded. Here is an extract from `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::successAction`:

```
    $session->clear();
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
    $this->renderLayout();
```

Answer (score 3):

I would say to do things after the rendering (and after sending away the response?)

If you want to do things before rendering, just use:

```
\Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::renderLayout
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:385
Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_layout_render_before_'.$this->getFullActionName());
```

Comment: Sorry, meant not "rendering" but "loading". Sure I can even use controller pre dispatching, but WHY?

Answer (score 3):

The only observer I can find for this event is from the Google Analystics module, which manipulates the layout.

So if we had no loaded layout -> GA module could not manipulate the layout.

Now we can discuss about if that is the best way to implement a change like that, but that might have been a effort/value decision. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from in the check out the only other place that I can see such behaviour is with the event `sendfriend_product`.

But this seems to be only used to report that the event has been fired...unless I am reading the code wrong.

It ends up writing to the `reports/event` with all the information from the event itself, though I am not sure why this would need to be done at this point.